# Destructive burst on entering Dragonsreach?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I enter Dragonsreach I emit a "burst" that levels up my destruction and kills someone and then makes all of the NPCs come after me.  I've reloaded old saves and tried going there to no avail and I've reloaded to the same save to see if it was a glitch but I have the same luck.  I'm now just avoiding Dragonsreach and using an old save, but does anyone know what it could be (and how I can stop it)?

Update: I went and assaulted a gaurd and paid off my bounty to see if that would fix it and it doesn't.  Also it's totally a gigantic lightning bolt.  But again, I'm not the source.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: Does it also happen when you enter using the dungeon?

Comment: Does it also happen if you enter through the backdoor or dungeon?

Comment: Which Platform are you using??

Answer (score 1):

The source is **probably a Rune**, I don't have any concrete evidence but I encountered something similar in Winterhold.

I was testing my new fire rune magic, and cast it on the wall next the door of the general store, forget about it, then when I came back with fast travel, the first thing I see is the exploding shopkeeper and an army of guards chasing me.

I don't remember how I got trough it, probably paid the price. But if it was rune, **you could try casting the same rune on somewhere**, because of the rune limit the new ones will dispel the older ones.